# Method to format a file size in AEM 6.1

Tags: jsp

In AEM 5.6 I used the `com.adobe.cq.social.commons.CollabUtil` API's function called `formatFileSize()` to get the size of file in bytes. Can anyone please tell me which API I should use in AEM 6.1 to get a size of file in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Class CQ.Util has a method called formatFileSize( Number size ) : String
Which Returns a human readable filesize including the unit, e.g "12 MB".